# Codeigneiter produce an internal server error with ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I stopped working on my codeigneiter app  because of this problem .  I'm using ajax (jquery) for the user registration script , But I get an Error 500 Internal server error when connecting to the controller , I read that the problem is related to CSRF , But the problem persist even if I turned CSRF off in the config file .

My ajax code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var controller = 'Auth';
 var base_url   = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';

  // User Registration
 $('#subm').click(function() 
 {  
     var username      = $("#username").val();
     var email         = $("#email").val();
     var password      = $("#password").val();
     var dataString    = $('#registerForm').serialize(); 


    if(username.length < 6 || username.length > 20)
     {
       $('#loader').hide();
       $('#errormsg').html("username length must be between 6 and 20 characters .") ; 
       $('.error-register').show(); 

     }

     // If everything is OK 
     else
     {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: base_url + controller + "/register",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(message)
           {      
              $('#loader').hide();
              if(message == true)
              {
                 $("#successModal").modal();
                 $('.notify').html("You have successfully Registered , Please Confirm Your Email !");
                 $("#username,#email,#password").val('');
              } 
              else 
              {
                  $('#errormsg').html(message) ; 
                  $('.error-register').show(); 

              }

           }
        });
      }

     return false;

 //End click 
 });

//End ready 
});
```

The Auth controller code is :

```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   class Auth extends CI_Controller 
   {
public function register()
{

      $email    = $this->input->post('email');
      $username = $this->input->post('username');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', '"username"',
     'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[52]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', '"email"',
     'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[52]|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', '"password"',
      'required|min_length[5]|max_length[52]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');

 if($this->form_validation->run())
     {    
       $this->load->model('users');
     if($this->users->register($username,$email,$password) === true)
     {           
         return true ; 
     }
     else
     {
        echo "Username or email already token" ; 
     }

   }
   else
   {
       echo  "please verify your inputs" ; 
   }
  }
 }
```

I really need help to continue working in this app.  Big thanks in advance .

Comment: What happens if you access the ajax url (yoursite.com/auth/register) directly in your browser?

Comment: It display  : please verify your inputs (the message in the controller )

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your ajax url correct ? (no missing slash between base_url + controller ?)
2. Did you load the form_validation ? `$this->load->library('form_validation');` and the url helper ? (for site_url)
3. (Optional : You don't need to check for true in your if, just do `if($this->users->register($username,$email,$password))`

EDIT

1. Is your controller file called auth.php ? (no other files with same name in Controller nor other controllers with same name ?)
2. Work with manual debug. Put everything in comments in your function, see if it still does a 500 error, in that case, maybe a .htaccess problem or an ajax problem (see with Firebug) ? If it works, uncomment until you find the problem.

EDIT 2

1. I believe this is an AJAX/.htaccess problem. Can you see with Firebug (if you are using Firefox) or with Chrome's console the http request sent ?
2. Can you create an other function in this controller and see if it works ?
3. Check if you don't have any hooks or routes (in your config/route/hook files) doing some logic that disables this controller. If everything is set to default, it shouldn't be the problem.
4. Finally, I bet that you put `true` to CSRF protection (in your config file). It doesn't work well with AJAX in CodeIgniter, so disable the CSRF value in your config file. It should work again. (There are other ways to prevent CSRF)

Comment: Thank you for your answer , form_validation library is already loaded in the autoload.php file , I checked the ajax URL ; no missing slashes , I still don't know the source of this problem .

Comment: auth.php is unique in the entire app . I putted everything in comment inside the function but the 500 error persist . I very sorry about my questions @BabyAzerty

Comment: edited my answer again. Short version of my edit : `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;`

Comment: Thank you so much , I created a new function in the auth controller that simply return a message when  using ajax  , It works well , chrome's console shows a 200 success code of xhr . I think the problem is related to the register function itself.

Comment: No problem ! If my answer did help, do not heistate to validate it ;)